# How to solve $y'' + (1-y)(1+y)y = 0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$y''+(1-y)(1+y)y =0 $$

I know that a specific solution is

$$\frac{e^{\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}} - e^{-\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}}}{e^{\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}} + e^{-\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}}}$$

but what's the general solution?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HyperbolicTangent.html

Comment: Wolfram Alpha gives ugly solutions: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%27+%2B+y+-+y%5E3%3D0&wal=header

Comment: @JeanMarie. It is not so bad if you switch $x$ and $y$ ("mon vieus dada !"). Cheers :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$y''+(1-y)(1+y)y =0$$ Swithch variables to get
$$-\frac{x''}{[x']^3}+(1-y)(1+y)y=0$$ Reduction of order $p=x'$ gives
$$p=x'=\pm \frac 1 {\sqrt{\frac{y^4}{2}-y^2+c_1 }}$$ and now, you will face an ugly ellptic integral.
$$x+c_2=\pm \int \frac {dy} {\sqrt{\frac{y^4}{2}-y^2+c_1 }}$$

Rewrite
$$\sqrt{\frac{y^4}{2}-y^2+c_1 }=\frac 1 {\sqrt 2} \sqrt{(y^2-a)(y^2-b)}$$ where $a$ and $b$ are the roots of the quadratic in $y^2$ and, hoping that I am not mistaken,
$$x+c_2=\pm \sqrt{\frac{2}{b}}F\left(\sin ^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{\sqrt{a}}\right)|\frac{a}{b}\right)$$

Do not try to inverse it (except if you want the monster @Jean Marie posted).

Comment: Perhaps a more intuitive method to get to your $p=x'$ equation is to multiply through by $y'$ and integrate once.

Comment: I just understood. Thank you, Claude.

Comment: "Do not try to invert it", yes, surely, but an afterthought: how could be retrieved for example the particular solution $\operatorname{argtanh(x/\sqrt{2})}$ given by the OP ?

Comment: @JeanMarie. I asked the same question to myself ! By the way, are you OK ? Cheers :-)